# I tried to make make foo return a pointer to fun2 but it doesn't seem to be working. What's the issue here? I want y to output 20

Tags: c, function-pointers

```
int (*foo(int(*f)(int,int)))(int,int)
{
    printf("hello");
    return f+1;
}

int fun1(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
int fun2(int x,int y)
{
    printf("hey");
    return x*y;
}

int main()
{
    int (*fun_ptr[2])(int,int);
    int x,y;
    fun_ptr[0]=&fun1;
    x=fun_ptr[0](4,5);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    fun_ptr[1]=&fun2;
   
    fun_ptr[0]=foo(fun_ptr[0]);
    y=fun_ptr[0](4,5);
    
    printf("%d",y);
    return 0;

}
```

I tried to make foo return a pointer to fun2 using return f+1. So it should (in my mind) point to the next element in the array fun_ptr where fun_ptr[1] is a pointer to fun2. So, y should be 20 but there's no output at all. x is being printed fine.

Answer (score 1):

In order for pointer arithmetic to work with arrays, the pointers must point to the elements of the arrays.  Here, you have an array of pointers to functions, so a pointer to an element would be **a pointer to a pointer to a function**.  That is `int (**)(int, int)`.

So if you change the declaration of foo to be

```
int (**foo(int(**f)(int,int)))(int,int)
```

it should work as you expect.  You'll also need to call it as `foo(&fun_ptr[0])`

Comment: Yeah. I barely know how function pointers worked when I posted this. Took me an hour but I got it before I saw this answer. This was a question on a test. So the answer was that it doesn't produce an output. But how to fix it? so that took me down a rabbit hole of returning a pointer to a function from a function taking a pointer to a function. You can see why it's complicated especially for a newbie like me. You figured it out in like a minute. I hope someday I can be that fast too

Comment: warning: assignment to 'int (*)(int,  int)' from incompatible pointer type 'int (**)(int,  int)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   29 |     fun_ptr[0]=foo(&fun_ptr[0]);
      |               ^

Answer (score 1):

The root problem is that you are using function pointers without `typedef`. This is simply a broken part of the language, don't waste time on trying to understand the syntax of contrived crap like "function taking an array of function pointers, returning a pointer to a function". There are very few cases where you'd do that in a real world program anyway. In the rare case you do - if you insist on writing obfuscated code like `int (*foo(int(**f)(int,int)))(int,int)` in a professional context, you'll get fired from your C programmer job.

Anything but this is madness:

```c
typedef int fun_t (int, int);

fun_t* foo (fun_t* f[])
{
    printf("hello");
    return f[1];
}

...

fun_ptr[0]=foo(fun_ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

```
int (*foo(int(**f)(int,int)))(int,int)
{
    
    return *f[1];
}

int fun1(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
int fun2(int x,int y)
{
    
    return x*y;
}

int main()
{
    int (*fun_ptr[2])(int,int);
    int x,y;
    fun_ptr[0]=&fun1;
    x=fun_ptr[0](4,5);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    fun_ptr[1]=&fun2;
    
    fun_ptr[0]=foo(&fun_ptr[0]);
    y=fun_ptr[0](4,5);
    
    printf("%d\n",y);
    return 0;

}
```

My `foo` function previously took a pointer to a function but, doing that, I couldn't travel 1 step inside the array `fun_ptr`. So, I took a step back and passed the address of the array of function pointers instead. This worked.

Comment: Though you may write return *f[1]; or even return *****f[1]; nevertheless it is better just to write return f1[1]; And also you may write for example  fun_ptr[0]=fun1; instead of fun_ptr[0]=&fun1;

Comment: why does this work? I mean this,".. instead of fun_ptr[0]=&fun1 "...and this " ...*f[1]; or even return *****f[1];..." ?

Comment: @Abhirup -- _"why does this work?"_ You can write, e.g., `fun_ptr[0]=fun1;` because `fun1` is a _function designator_, and function designators are converted to function pointers in most expressions. You can return `f[1]` instead of `*f[1]` because dereferencing a function pointer yields a function designator, which is converted to a function pointer in most expressions.